# WP blog posts index URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to use WP for a site that blog is just one aspect of it, and I don't want requests to `home_url` list blog posts (`post_type=post`), I want them be to fetched using another URL.

This topic [default-archive-url-wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30037/default-archive-url-wordpress) suggest two ways:

1. `page_for_posts` option
2. `post_type=post` URL query parameter

but I have questions

About the first, How a `page` would be able to `loop` into the posts, and where I should update this option (which `hook`)?

For the second, the guy says that using this param, make the wordpress get the archive for the specified post type, but I think posts don't have archive (according to `includes/post.php` their `has_archive` is left to default) how should I change this and also I want to use a `permalink`/pretty link for accessing posts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings -> reading, and change the front page displays posts settings to front page displays a static page and then select a blog page.

Easy as pie.